# C++ Array Sorting, Memory Error?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, visual-studio-2012

I'm learning C++ programming, and I am having trouble with a basic array sort program. My code seems to not throw any compiler errors - VisualStudio2012 doesn't show any errors. Also, it seems exactly like the code I found on my tutorial (learncpp.com).

The output is supposed to show an array at every step of its selection sort. However I keep getting different outputs of random letters and numbers. Is this a memory problem? Or something else?

Also, the commented out 'if' loop was how I'd swap array elements in 1 line instead of 2 lines of code. Would that work for sorting?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
using namespace std;

const int nSize = 6;
int anArray[nSize] = {30, 60, 20, 50, 40, 10};

for (int nStartIndex = 0; nStartIndex < nSize; nStartIndex++){
    int nSmallestIndex = nStartIndex;

    for (int nCurrentIndex = nSmallestIndex + 1; nCurrentIndex < nSize; nCurrentIndex++){


    /*  if (anArray[nCurrentIndex] < anArray[nSmallestIndex])
            swap(anArray[nSmallestIndex], anArray[nCurrentIndex]);
    */

        if (anArray[nCurrentIndex] < anArray[nSmallestIndex])
        nSmallestIndex = nCurrentIndex;
    }

    swap(anArray[nStartIndex], anArray[nSmallestIndex]);

    cout << "The current array: \t" << anArray << "\n";

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I somewhat have the feeling that the real code has a char isntead of int for that array...

Comment: Well, doing `cout << "The current array: \t" << anArray << "\n";` won't print the array itself. It will print the **address** of the array. In the case of a `char` array, you'll get the contents of the array, but that's only because `<<` handles `char` arrays specially.

Comment: The swap works, just un-comment it and try.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, check the link http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/64-sorting-an-array-using-selection-sort/
Exact same, except with different array.

Comment: oh and thanks Nik, I didn't think of that, guess you solved my problem. I'm new to stack overflow, so can I upvote your comment? I don't see a "like" button haha..

Comment: @NewtoProgramming You're welcome; don't worry about upvoting my comment, just focus on learning. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your displaying, something like `0x23abcd` is a memory address. You are actually displaying the pointer to the first element in the array.
To display an array properly in C++11, the best way is to use a range-for loop:

```
for(int &i : anArray)
        std::cout << i << " ";
```

Comment: I don't think I've learned about the "&" symbol yet, but I'll just make my own loop. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try using a loop to output the content of the array.

```
for(int i=0; i<anArray.size(); i++)
    std::cout<< anArray[i] << " ";
```

Edit: The solution given by @awesomeyi looks more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the code portion :

```
cout << "The current array: \t" << anArray << "\n";
```

use this

```
cout << "The current array: \t";
for(int i=0;i<nSize;i++)
{
    cout<<anArray[i]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
```

this will work I think, another thing as you are using the header `<algorithm>` you can use a function `sort()` to sort an array in `nlogn` complextiy. An example here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
using namespace std;

const int nSize = 6;
int anArray[nSize] = {30, 60, 20, 50, 40, 10};

sort(anArray,anArray+6);

    cout << "The current array: \t";
    for(int i=0;i<nSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<anArray[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;



return 0;
}
```